# How to use GVFS to launch an X program with super user permissions?

Tags: ubuntu, gvfs, gksudo

I'm trying to port a script to Ubuntu 18.04 that uses `gksudo` to prompt the user for admin password in order to run a GUI program with the admin permissions.
Now, `gksudo` has been removed from Ubuntu 18.04 and I understand that `gvfs` with the admin backend is the recommended alternative (as described in [this article](https://itsfoss.com/gksu-replacement-ubuntu/) and elsewhere).
However, I am having trouble running it (My current environment is 16.04, haven't tried on 18.04 yet)

```
:~$ ls -l /home/luke/test
-rw--w---- 1 root root 22 Jan 23 10:36 /home/luke/test
:~$ gedit admin:///home/luke/test
** (gedit:32552): WARNING **: The specified location is not supported
```

`gedit` itself runs, saying:

> Could not open the file “admin:///home/luke/test”.
>      Unable to handle “admin:” locations

Trying to run nautilus fails similarly.
How do I use `gvfs` to launch an `X` program with super user permissions?

Comment: identical behaviour with $USER or the actual hardcoded path. The hardcoded path is what I tried first. edited question to remove this complication.

Comment: I found `gvfs-backends` as source of this error [in a far past](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1883938)... did you installed them? BTW good luck.

Comment: thanks for suggestion - yes I had that installed already.

Comment: Where exactly did you try running this command line? I’d guess this only works in “GNOME-y” locations—where GVFS is supported in the first place.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "GNOME-y" locations.
I'm running it with gnome-terminal in the same folder as the file - /home/luke/